# Milvus throws exception after inserting a large number of rows

Tags: exception

After inserting a large number of rows (approx. 3 million) I receive an error as shown below.
The rows are inserted 10,000 at a time.
The length of each embedding is 384.

When inserting embeddings with twice the length the same or similar error occurs after approx. 1M to 1.5M segments.

Stacktrace:

```
 - File   
   "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/collection.py",
   line 431, in insert    timeout=timeout, schema=self._schema_dict,
   **kwargs)
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py",
   line 109, in handler    raise e
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py",
   line 105, in handler    return func(*args, **kwargs)
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py",
   line 136, in handler    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py",
   line 85, in handler    raise e
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py",
   line 50, in handler    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py",
   line 399, in batch_insert    raise err
        File    "/ec/dgt/local/exodus/home/ewetzha/dev/enginefactory-dev/artefacts/venvs/venv-sentencetransformer/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py",
   line 395, in batch_insert    raise
   MilvusException(response.status.error_code, response.status.reason)
          pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=1,    message=getSegmentID failed: SegmentIDAllocator
   failRemainRequest    unexpected error)>
```

The only (?) way to continue and insert rows is to stop Milvus and the start it again.